# FastAPI is not working like expected in Async Mode

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, fastapi

I need to build an API using FastAPI with the following requirements:

Should be Async

Accepts a PDF and input

Split the pdf to images

call 3 api endpoints for each image synchronously

It should be something like promise.all of nodejs where you wait for all the apis calls of all the images are completed

When I do so in FastAPI the requests are not accepted/processed parallely, while in node it is otherwise.

** Note: I'm using single uvicorn worker and as per FastAPI calim single worker should be able to process parllel requests.

Please help me and let me know what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Refer to the screenshot below.

[Log Comparision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oVys.png)
LHS is the FastAPI log and RHS is NodeJS log file

Refer to the code I used.

https://gist.github.com/shreyasY2k/8301bd78ca8593c59fb4368b8e64aba9

In NodeJS, even if 2 requests are sent at a time they are accepted and processed in near parallel fashion while FastAPI processes 2nd request only after the first one is complete.

Comment: `async` does not mean parallell. Please include the relevant code you're asking about in the question itself as a minimum verifiable example. If you're using async, you'll need to write async compatible code: `requests.get(api_url)` is not async compatible; use httpx or another async compatible http library in Python - or just define your endpoints as regular endpoints and skip using async if you don't have async compatible libraries on all levels. `async` is cooperative multitasking, so you'll need to cooperate (which is what `await` does)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/shreyasY2k/8301bd78ca8593c59fb4368b8e64aba9#file-main-py-L20 - as previous comment said - you're mixing synchronous library with async.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh changed to httpx now it's working as expected. I was of the notion that whatever may be the library, FastAPI will force everything to be async. But now understood that we need to use only Async compatible libraries. In nodejs we can make any task async irrespective of whether a library it supports or not.